# Blind SQL Injection on Amazon RDS

Tags: sql-injection, mysql, amazon

I found a vulnerability which allows me to run any query on an Amazon RDS server. I was able to extract the user hashes by using the --passwords parameter of sqlmap, and one of the hashes was cracked before. The thing is, I'm not sure that first the Amazon RDS Instance is accessible from the internet (specifically any IP), and I'm not sure how I could get the ip of the RDS instance (--hostname returns internal 172.x.x.x address). I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to further escalate the vulnerability.

Comment: Is this your own account or part of a pentest? IOW, do you have console access to the AWS environment?

Comment: @HashHazard part of a pentest

Comment: Will be tough. If you had console you could see any public endpoints that may be attached to the RDS instance. By default they are only accessible using the RFC 1918 schema.

Comment: In RDS/MySQL, the value of `@@hostname` is especially meaningless because there is an undocumented static NAT translation layer between the AWS customer's network and the RDS-managed network, so the private IP you see there has no actual relevance, even if you were inside their network by some other mechanism.  It isn't even the internal address the client machines are connecting to.  If it's actually an Aurora/MySQL instance (`SELECT @@AURORA_VERSION`), you could try invoking a Lambda function in *your* account, and use *your* CloudTrail to see which principal was denied access. Maybe useful.

Answer (score 1):

Two options come immediately to mind -

**Exfiltration**

You can learn more by Googling 'sql injection exfiltration', but generally, this involves using SQL primitives that make [DNS lookups](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/identifying-host-names-and-addresses) or [HTTP connections](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ac224833-1ffa-4008-880c-ce8f4d442110/trying-to-obtain-xml-data-from-url-via-sql?forum=sqlxml).  You can build a query that selects data from a table and injects it into a host lookup to a domain that you control; then your DNS server will see the data.

This option takes advantage of the fact that while you may not have a good route to the database, it probably has some sort of route outbound.  DNS, especially, is indirect and can be used even if the DB server itself has zero Internet access.

**Front End Leverage**

If the database (and credentials accessible within) are backend for a front end web UI that *is* accessible over the network, then you can use the information to get into the app, which may be just as useful as getting into the database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For reference, this is a MySQL server, and I was going to do an HTTP connection, but unfortunately that didn't work. I'll see if there is anything else I can do before trying to attack the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and report this directly to Amazon, see https://aws.amazon.com/security/vulnerability-reporting/ and it would be good to know what the follow up is from them.

Comment: My question isn't "what should I do with it", it's "what can I do with it to further escalate the vulnerability"...

Comment: Ok. I had read 'escalate' in the way of 'escalating to Amazon.'